# QCad successfully installed but will not launch

Tags: linux

I installed QCad on Crunchbang Linux, Waldorf using `synaptic`. Now when I check in terminal, it is installed

```
$ sudo apt-get install qcad
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
qcad is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 256 not upgraded.
```

But when I try to run it, this is what I get:

```
$ qcad
bash: qcad: command not found
```

Any thoughts what the problem might be?

Comment: check `/var/log/apt/history.log` to find out what qcad binary is named

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian replaced QCad by LibreCAD, a fork that's fully free software. The [qcad package](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/qcad) in Debian wheezy (which Crunchbang is based on — it's getting really old) is a basically empty package that depends on [librecad](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/librecad), it's just there to facilitate upgrades. The real software is in the librecad package and it's called `librecad`.

You can list the files in the qcad package with

```
dpkg -L qcad
```

You'll see that there are [very few files](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/qcad/filelist), and `/usr/share/doc/qcad/NEWS.Debian.gz` will tell you what's going on.

The information is also present in the description of the `qcad` package which you can see with

```
dpkg -s qcad
```

or `apt-cache show qcad` (which works even if `qcad` isn't installed).

Comment: I see. Good point, thanks for explaining.